# How can I add other online accounts?

Tags: empathy, pidgin, online-accounts

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I'd like to add other online account (like QQ, weibo) in empathy or pidgin. How can I ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QQ,Webio is not supported any more by Ubuntu.

There is a QQ plugin available for pidgin.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lainme/libqq/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lainme/libqq/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
```

[ppa:lainme/libqq  [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~lainme/+archive/libqq) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

For weibo : http://libpurple-microblog-sina.googlecode.com provides a plugin you can download the [source](https://code.google.com/p/libpurple-microblog-sina/downloads/detail?name=libpurple-microblog-sina-0.1.tar.gz&can=2&q=) and install it.